# how to do a URL pathing(?) & .php vs .html

Tags: php, html, url

`".com/watch?v=M0IDGz0QKDw"` I'm a beginner and I wanna know how to do this. Can someone point me out onto where I can learn this url pathing?

And also if .php is way better than .html because php is connected to the database then what is this ".com/messages" weren't it supposed to be `".com/messages.php"` 
note that messages gets all messages to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First -> ".com/watch?v=M0IDGz0QKDw"

it is that there is **v** means some variable with unique number.
And **watch** means in MVC architecture we have route.config file there we will configure the watch.php file.So the routing URL is like that.

Second : Yes always better to use in MVC architecture .

So try to learn MVC architecture by some frameworks like laravel, Codeigniter etc.it may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

`".com/watch?v=M0IDGz0QKDw"`

**watch** is actually watch.php or watch.html, file extension is hidden from URL display.
This setting is depends on framework or .htaccess setting.
You can refer to https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

`v=M0IDGz0QKDw`

**v** is variable name, while **M0IDGz0QKDw** is value.
In this case, **watch** page is using $_GET method to collect data from URL.
You can learn that from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

HTML and PHP are different language and serve different purpose.
In short, HTML handle display, while PHP handle business flow and logic.

I would suggest you learn how to manage data with PHP first, then only proceed to configure .htaccess for hiding file extension. It will be ease for you to do troubleshoot during coding.